# How do I open a link by clicking on an item name?

Tags: jquery

[link to the code page](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184)

I tried to add the following code but I do not know what to write instead of SEL-NAME (the name of the item you clicked on).

```
.on('click', function(){
   window.location = "editor://open/?file=C:\Users\sm\Documents\website\SEL-NAME.php&line=1"
});
```

Will someone please help me to add jQuery code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please state clearly what the problem is, what problem you're facing, and include all *relevant* code in the question.

Comment: What on earth is the problem?

Comment: I need to get the name of the item I clicked on...

Comment: You have it in the click event, it is $(this).attr("name")

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll try to help with very little to go on

Change:

```
.on('click', function(){
   window.location = "editor://open/?file=C:\Users\sm\Documents\website\SEL-NAME.php&line=1"
});
```

to:

```
.on('click', function(){
   window.location = "editor://open/?file=C:\Users\sm\Documents\website\" + $(this).attr("name") + ".php&line=1";
});
```

Comment: error:
(index):113 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at SVGTextElement.<anonymous> ((index):113)
    at SVGTextElement.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):113
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2

Comment: index line 113 : console.log($(this).attr("name"));

Comment: This means that you don't have jquery included.  Add this: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Does the element that you are clicking on have a name or and id?

Comment: it's ID but it does not work..console.log($(this).attr("id"));Result : (index):113 undefined